# Python - cx_oracle Update throws ORA-01036

Tags: python, cx-oracle

our UPDATE statement looks like this:

```
upd = """UPDATE prices \
         SET pre_after_price = :1, \
             volume = :2, \
             pre_after_updated = SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' HOUR \
         WHERE ticker = :3"""
```

Then, the actual code is this:

```
cursor.execute(upd,([pre_after_price, volume, ticker]))
```

But rather, we get this error:

```
ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
dpiStmt_bindByPos: bind by position
```

Is there something we are doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can issue this statement first:

```py
cursor.prepare(upd)
print("bind names:", cursor.bindnames())
```

That should tell you which bind names are expected!

If you use the new thin mode of python-oracledb (replacement for cx_Oracle) cursor.execute() provides more useful information about what is missing or incorrect. If you're not aware of the new driver I would recommend checking it out! https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/

Comment: Did are you suggested and got this:     bind names: ['1', '2', '3']

Comment: Which looks correct. So at that point you are probably going to need to set the envrionment variable `DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL` to the value 28 and run your code again (and post the results in your question). I'll update my answer appropriately. The error you are getting suggests that you are supplying more bind variables than the SQL statement expects.